# Clip (Modify Features) aggregates nearby geometry using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, buffer, clip, aggregation, modify-features

I have a large polygon that contains several other (smaller) polygons. Some of these smaller polygons also intersect with each other but they all at least 'touch' the larger polygon.

I want to clip this larger polygon with a unionized version of these smaller polygons (i.e. symmetrical difference/erase depending on your GIS of choice).

There are several ways you can do this but most of these require several steps and some temporary files. ArcGIS Pro has an `Clip` editor tool that should allow me to do all necessary steps at once and inplace (i.e. just modifies the existing geometries). It unfortunately does appear to aggregate nearby polygons (**not touching**) even when the optional buffer is set to 0.

You can test this yourself by opening a new feature class and drawing 2 nearby (again, not touching) rectangles (i.e. the input features) enclosed by a larger square (i.e. the target feature; see screenshot): [image]

Is there some environmental setting that I'm not aware of that causes this behaviour?

I'm running ArcGIS Pro 2.5.2

Answer (score 0):

It was the XY tolerance. This value dictates the minimum value between coordinates and was unfortunately much larger than the distances between some of my input features. The easiest way to fix it in ArcGIS Pro < 2.6 was to just configure the XY Tolerance in a new geodatabase and to copy the feature class there. Clip from Modify Features now works as expected if given this feature class.